# Visual Composer vc_map() dynamic dropdowns & dependency

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer

I am currently playing around with Visual Composer and [vc_map()](https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/inner-api/vc_map/) for a personal project. I would like to have a dropdown in an element dependent on another dropdown in the same element. So let's say I have games and tournaments, once a user selects a game, I would like to make an API call, get the tournaments for that game and update the vc tournament dropdown accordingly.

I am populating params on a dropdown params type after fetching the data from an API as can be seen below:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../vc_templates/api_base.php');
$apiBase = new ApiBase();       
$games_array = $apiBase->getGamesData(true);
$tournaments_array = $apiBase->getActiveTournamentsData(true);

vc_map( array(
            'name'        => 'Name',
            'base'        => 'test_element',
            'description' => 'Description',
            'params'      => array(
                array(
                    'type'        => 'dropdown',
                    'heading'     => esc_html__( 'Game', 'prjct' ),
                    'param_name'  => 'game_id',
                    'value'       => $games_array,
                    'description' => esc_html__( 'Select a game to display.', 'prjct' ),
                    'admin_label' => true,
                    'std'         => 0,
                ),
                array(
                    'type'        => 'dropdown',
                    'heading'     => esc_html__( 'Tournament', 'prjct' ),
                    'param_name'  => 'tournament_id',
                    'value'       => $tournaments_array,
                    'description' => esc_html__( 'Select a tournament to display.', 'prjct' ),
                    'admin_label' => true,
                    'std'         => 0,
                )
)
));
```

Now I've looked into the [Param Dependencies](https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/inner-api/vc_map/#vc_map()-param-dependenciesParamDependencies) however this is only used to show or hide an element based on another element, so it's not what I need. I spent quite some time looking into this and going through various online articles however I couldn't find an application of vc_map similar to what I'm looking for. Is this because it simply cannot be done with Visual Composer's vc_map limitations? Or am I getting something wrong and not reading the documentation properly?

Answer (score 0):

I did not encounter an issue like this yet so I'm not sure if it is a limitation or not, but the documentation doesn't help.

I would look into 'admin_enqueue_js' & 'admin_enqueue_css' and modify the dropdown based on the data you get back with JS.